# Matrix vector multiplication convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a $n \times n$ matrix $M$ and a $n$-dimensional vector $s_0$.

And $s_{k+1}=M*s_k$.

What properties does $M$ have to have for that iteration to converge?

Comment: I'm not sure about in general, but if $s_0$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $| \lambda | <1$, then this converges.

Comment: It will always converge for any $s_0$ if all the eigenvectors of $M$ have absolute value less than 1.